# Тире после запятой

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, обращение

Подскажите, нужно ли ставить тире после запятой и слова "господа" или в данном случае достаточно запятой?

*А сейчас прошу меня извинить, господа, мне что-то снова нехорошо.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***А сейчас прошу меня извинить, господа, // мне что-то снова нехорошо.***

Предложение оформлено верно, то есть здесь достаточно запятой.

**Пояснение**

1. **Общее решение**

Это бессоюзное сложное предложение (БСП), отношения между двумя частями не однородные, а **взаимообусловленные**. В таком случае возможна постановка **трех знаков** – двоеточия, тире и запятой, поэтому нужно сделать выбор.

2. **Как делается выбор**

Нужно определить  **смысловые отношения** более конкретно. Вторая часть поясняет первую, указывая **причину** (почему требуется извинение).

Классический вариант в этом случае – это **двоеточие** (пояснительные или причинно-следственные отношения, причем причина стоит на втором месте).

**Тире** может заменять  двоеточие, в устной речи при этом делается пауза меньшей длительности. Так мы обозначаем **только  взаимообусловленность**, но направление этой связи не указываем (нам не так важно, что причина находится на втором месте).

Но двоеточие и тире – сильные знаки, мы не так часто используем их для оформления обычной речи. Поэтому возможен вариант **с запятой**. Тогда мы указываем только то, что вторая часть **распространяет** первую, то есть продолжает начатую тему.

3. **Вывод**

Запятая здесь более **предпочтительный** знак, так как в конце первой части расположено обособленное запятыми обращение.